# PyOpenCL, OpenCL, can see but cant use CPU as device

Tags: parallel-processing, opencl, pyopencl

With

```
import pyopencl as cl
platform = cl.get_platforms()[1]
device   = platform.get_devices()
```

I have two devices :

```
<pyopencl.Device 'Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-3570K CPU @ 3.40GHz' on 'Intel(R) OpenCL' at 0x9f7a0e0>, 

<pyopencl.Device 'Intel(R) HD Graphics 4000' on 'Intel(R) OpenCL' at 0x9efdab0>
```

with

```
device   = platform.get_devices()[0]
```

I chose the CPU as my device. However, if I use the CPU to create a context (ctx      = cl.Context([device])   ). I got this error:

```
RuntimeError: clCreateContext failed: DEVICE_NOT_AVAILABLE
```

But the context worked for my two GPU (Intel Graphic, and GTX970 on platform[0]).

Any idea why this error happened?

Many thanks

Jiajun

Comment: check if you have another cpu platform, that may work. also some platforms are cpu only

Comment: I've seen this error when the CPU doesn't meet the minimum requirement for the Intel OpenCL CPU driver (for example, a certain SSE level). It still shows up as a device but fails to create a context.

Comment: @Dithermaster this could be a problem. the CPU is i5 3xxx series. Could be a bit too old?

Comment: @huseyintugrulbuyukisik, yes there is another CPU platform but also didn't work. I will try to get the error message for that.